# TypeScript: How to merge interface declarations that use the same global property?

Tags: typescript, types, interface

I have a typescript project that uses multiple cordova plugins. Each plugin initializes on a global `plugins` object, like so:

```
// Plugin A init
window.plugins.pluginA = {...};

// Plugin B init
window.plugins.pluginB = {...};
```

However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to do the types so that each plugin can extend the `plugins` object without knowing about the other plugins. The 2nd plugin's types throw an error because the `plugins` object has already been defined. How can I structure it to extend it instead?

```
// Plugin A's type declarations
interface IPluginA {
    methodA: (foo: number) => void
}
interface Window {
    plugins: {
        pluginA: IPluginA;
    };
}

// Plugin B's type declarations
interface IPluginB {
    methodB: (bar: string) => void
}
interface Window {
    // ERROR: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.
    //     Property 'plugins' must be of type '{pluginA: IPluginA};'
    plugins: {
        pluginB: IPluginB;
    };
}
```

Comment: Curious if you ever solved this, @frodo2975

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't. I ended up manually copying both plugins' types into my project in a manually created unified interface.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand what you want to do is to join type from two other types which have some common structure - `plugins` property. In order to achieve that we can use union type - `type Union = A | B`.

In your example it would be:

```
// specific plugins types
type IPluginA = {
    methodA: (foo: number) => void
}
type IPluginB = {
    methodB: (bar: string) => void
}

type WindowA = {
  plugins: {
      pluginA?: IPluginA
    }
}

type WindowB = {
  plugins: {
      pluginB?: IPluginB
    }
}

type MyWindow = WindowA | WindowB; // here union of both

const win: MyWindow = {
  plugins: {
    // pluginA and pluginB as fields
  }
}
```

If there will be new plugins we can attached them further to `MyWindow`, thanks to that our final type will have available all possible plugins. Take a look also that I put optional fields there, as it is possible to not have all plugins, but only part of them.

Comment: Unfortunately, creating my own subtype of Window isn't really an option. These plugins are supposed to be plug-n-play, so that a user can just install them and they just work, so I can't expect people to have to create their own window type.